# exec-shell returned: 1 Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1 exec-shell returned: 1 Package Generation failed for platform Android

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

```
Package Generation failed for platform Android. See console for details  
exec-shell returned: 1  
Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1  
exec-shell returned: 1
```

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;E:\Konyjk\kony7.1\ImageMagick;%ANT_HOME%\lib;E:\Konyjk\androidsdk\platform-tools;E:\Konyjk\androidsdk\tools;E:\Konyjk\kony7.1installation\Ant\bin;Kony Visualizer 
Enterprise Edition

Version: 7.1

Comment: During my first Application i got Android sdk problem .

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issues and resolved once  "Android Support Repository" from the Android SDK manager is installed.

Comment: What that's mean? how?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time you are trying to build the app, please check the below things.

1. All the required Android SDK files are available and Path is configured properly in Visualizer->Preference tab.
2. Connected to open internet connection (For the very first tine build, if any of the required files are not available, Kony Visualizer tres to download it from internet. One time only). If you are on a restricted network, this may be an issue.

You can post the full log to understand the situation better.

Hope this helps!